# prove that the general solution of a homogenous Second order DE is unique or any other solution of the DE is in the form of the general solution?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let $y_1,y_2$ be fundamental set of solutions of a homogenous second order DE, I want to show that any other solutions came from or is a combination of $y_1$ and $y_2$ and is a general solution
$Y(x)=c_{1}y_{1}+c_{2}y_{2}$

Comment: Take the course of the theory of ODEs! :)

Comment: @H.R.i  am taking applied math 3

Comment: This question is a theoretical one so if you want to know why, you may study the theory of ordinary differential equations. Also, a knowledge of linear algebra is necessary. Applied math 3 just tell you how to do the computation but not the theory and ideas behind these computations! :)

Comment: @H.R. What books do you recommend?

Comment: As you are not a math student I do suggest you to read the [Calculus I of Tom. A. Apostol](http://www.amazon.com/Calculus-Vol-One-Variable-Introduction-Algebra/dp/0471000051/ref=sr_1_2?ie=UTF8&qid=1447745668&sr=8-2&keywords=tom.+m.+apostol+calculus). There is a chapter in the book dealing with ODE's and it answers your question in some tidy way. The classic is the [book by Coddingtone](http://www.amazon.com/Theory-Ordinary-Differential-Equations-Coddington/dp/0898747554/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1447745698&sr=1-1&keywords=theory+of+ordinary+differential+equations) which may frustrate you!

Comment: Your statement isn't exactly true if the coefficient of the highest order derivative is allowed to vanish somewhere inside the interval of interest.